# Using a while(1) loop as a makeshift state machine in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, state-machine

So I have seen that many suggestions on implementing a state machine in C involve a state struct or the like, but I was wondering why we can't just use a while(1) for very simple state machines. For example,

```
 int currentstate = state1;

 void state1function(){
    dosomething();
    if(user chooses to go to state 2){
       currentstate = state2;
    }
 }

 int main{
    while(1){
       if(currentstate == state1){
          state1function();
       }
       else if (currenstate == state2){
          state2function();
 }
```

Basically keeping track of the state in a global variable, and in the while loop calling a function depending on the state. This seems simple to me and i don't really see why it wouldn't work.

Can anyone please tell me why something like this would not work/would not be recommended?

Thanks

Comment: You have a confuse. Actually infinite loop is used for state machine in many embedded system.

Comment: For bare-bone programming on embedded systems without any OS, this is roughly how simple applications look like. But most often, the applications are not that simple, because they have a lot of things to do. Sooner or later, you will end having more than 1 state variable (state machines) for various aspects of the system you program and this basic approach will lead to error prone, hard to maintain spaghetti code.

Comment: Real programmers use global state!

Comment: in general, when using a `while(1)` loop where the body of the loop is the state machine:  1) each state invokes a separate sub function.  2) each sub function returns the next state (which may be the current state). 3) states are selected/executed via a switch statement that has 1 `case` for each possible state.  Amongst other things, the `state` value is kept to a local variable and the loop does not need to know anything about what a `state` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sooner or later, using this approach, you will find that it would be convenient to have:

- An explicit transition table.
- `OnEntry(), OnExit(), Do(), OnEvent()` functions for each state.
- Actions performed on a transition.
- Guards. (explicit conditions for transitions to be triggered)
- Nested state machines.
- Concurrent state machines. Meaning: Multiple FSM running next to each other.
- Communicating concurrent, nested state machines.

Somewhere along this ladder of sophistication, you will most likely abandon the brute force style, you started with, which might have looked like the code you gave in your question.

The `while(1)` construct is quite unrelated to state machines. It is used whenever a single thread of execution (main() or OS threads) are long-running, as they typically are on embedded systems or server-applications. If the application is written in form of a state machine or in other forms, does not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the problem you're trying to solve, a global or a static is a straightforward solution.  Using a struct comes in handy when you need to manage more than one state machine at a time, and/or when you need to change state from more than one thread or process.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop without wait will consume lot of CPU. I think an event mechanism using mutex or seamphores will be useful.

Comment: Whether it chews up the CPU depends on what the `dosomething()` function does, and how the user chooses to go to state 2.  In general, it depends on the actions performed by the state machine.  If there's nothing that waits for some event to occur, then there'll be problems; if there's anything that waits, then there probably won't.

Answer (score 0):

C is not  asynchronous (by default). An infinite loop will just cause your program to "freeze" until the results are done.

Comment: A "freeze" will only (necessarily) occur on a multi threaded single CPU (core) system. If the system is an embedded system with a single thread, as noted above, there won't (necessarily) be a problem. If the system is multi core and multi threaded, then whether the program freezes is dependent on how it's designed. If it has another thread that drives the UI or otherwise responds to requests that must be responded to for the system to be considered responsive there won't (necessarily) be a problem.